# How Floyd Warshall Algorithm Works In Below Case

Tags: algorithm, directed-graph

Suppose I have 9 vertices.
So I have 9x9 solution matrix and

```
matrix[6,0] = infinity, 
matrix[6,9]=1, 
matrix[9,0]=1
```

Now algorithm works like below:

```
for k 1 to 9
    for i 1 to 9
        for j 1 to 9
```

Now suppose `k=6`

so for `matrix[5,0]` comparison would be between (`matrix[5,6]+matrix[6,0]`) & `matrix[5,0]` in this case `matrix[6,0] = infinity` so `matrix[5,0]` will be the value.

But when `k=9`

`matrix[6,0]` becomes => `matrix[6,9] + matrix[9,0] = 1 + 1 = 2`

But there is no way to update `matrix[5,0]` now.

That's my understanding. So how does the algorithm works in this case.

Comment: what about other edges? matrix[5,6] ,is it infinity or 0?

Comment: It is 0. Can someone help with the explanation please?

Answer (score 0):

If your loops starts from 0 and other values are 0 except `matrix[6]{0,9}` and `matrix[9][0]`
then 
`matrix[6][0]` will be updated from `matrix[6][1]+matrix[1][0]`
`matrix[6][9]` will be updated from `matrix[6][1]+matrix[1][9]`
`matrix[9][0]` will be updated from `matrix[9][1]+matrix[1][0]`
You don't need to update `matrix[5][0]` cause its already 0?
Basically when you have `K` value in `loop k` that means You are about to add another edge and  all possible way to go from `(i->j)` is updated using `edges(1->K-1)`.
Then you insert another edge `K` and you again check if there is any way to go from `(i->j)` in cheaper way using this edge . 
so you write `matrix[i][j]=min(matrix[i][j],matrix[i][k]+matrix[k][j])`